# Search View is not opening in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse

I wanted to search a constant in my workspace so that I could find all the files where this constant is use. 
So on the Menu I clicked on Search -> File -> Entered the constant name and hit the search button.

Ideally when I do this a Search view is automatically opened that displays the search result. Currently this view is not opening.

Then as an alternative I tried finding the reference of the Constant in the workspace. Even that didn't work as no view is opening in my Eclipse.

I am using Eclipse Java EE IDE Luna Release (4.4.0).

Comment: go to Windows->Show View->Search,,,this should bring up the search view

Comment: Hi @Saurav....I did try that like i normally do......but still it is not showing....that is why i posted this question

Comment: What is the error you get in the error log when you try to open the search view ?

Comment: Error while creating link to external folder: D:\Workspace\

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This problem got resolved. Try using below solutions:

1. **Window** -> **New Window**.
         OR
2. **Window** -> **Reset Perspective**.